# Tool similar to Dynatrace

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there anything out there which is similar to this tool?  I'm hoping to do some verification of our caching setup with Hibernate.

I found [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/), but it seems that the project is dead.

Is there any other good profiling tool out there to verify Hibernate Caching configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried yourkit? In J2EE mode it can show you the Database calls you app does. If you dont implement caching properly it will show you the extra calls. It has a free 30 day trial. Should be enough for a one off test

Comment: Just a note, the trial period is down to 15 days now.  I'm looking into this now.

Comment: I did have some luck, but found it pretty simple to also inspect the Hibernate Statistics as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could try jvisualvm, it is bundled with the jvm since 1.6_10.
It should enable you to inspect the heap and stack, even against jvm's that are running on a remote host.